# Why overlapping comparisons always evaluate to true when comparing int with enum?

Tags: c++

My compiler Clang throw following warning when compiling the program,

```
 warning: overlapping comparisons always evaluate to true [-Wtautological-overlap-compare]
 if(someProtocolValue != protocol::tls ||
```

Here is the enum,

```
enum protocol
{
    http = 1,
    tls = 2,
    ws = 3,
    wss = 4
};
```

And, I'm trying to compare an int value with this protocol enum like this,

```
            // This is dynamic, but in this case ...
            int someProtocolValue = 2;

            if(someProtocolValue != protocol::tls ||
               someProtocolValue  != protocol::wss) {
                // Do work
             }
```

I don't see anything wrong. Why do this `someProtocolValue != protocol::tls ||` statement evaluate to true according to the compiler?

Comment: It's not possible for `someProtocolValue` to be equal to `protocol::tls` _and_ `protocol::wss` simultaneously. So _at least one_ of `someProtocolValue != protocol::tls` and `someProtocolValue != protocol::wss` is always true. Therefore the logical OR of those two expressions is always true. Did you mean `&&`?

Comment: write out a truth table for `x != 2 || x != 3`, is there a value of `x` where the statement isn't true?

Comment: @NathanPierson This blinded me for real. Yeah,  && indeed correct ..

Comment: @AlanBirtles Right, just blind me..

Comment: @NathanPierson I did try with && and now it gives me `overlapping comparisons always evaluate to false`

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the exact code that is now failing?

Comment: @NathanPierson I'm really blind. Never mind, it was another separate statement that got && by mistake when doing replaceAll on my text editor. Actually that statement is reverse of what's above.